# A Random Riddle

Tags: riddle

My friend gave me this short riddle, but it took me quite a while to find the answer. Thought the Puzzling community would like to have a go at it!

> Made of wood and metal, I get you home. 
>   Made of blood and flesh, in the darkness I roam. 
>   What am I?

Comment: The title "A Random Riddle" is kind of misleading.  Was looking forward to so some random element being incorporated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you

> **Bat**

Made of wood and metal, I get you home.

> Baseball bat for Home Run.

Made of blood and flesh, in the darkness I roam.

> The mammal.

Comment: Yep, got it right!

Comment: Wasn't this already done, and it like blew up on the HNQ?

Answer (score 15):

Are you the word

> Bat

Explanation

Made of wood and metal, I get you home.

> Bat made with Wood or Metal

Made of blood and flesh, in the darkness I roam.

> Bat made with blood and flesh that flies in night

Answer (score 12):

Are you (alternatively)

> A Jaguar

Made of wood and metal, I get you home.

> Jaguar cars are made of wood (interior) and metal 
>  [image]

Made of blood and flesh, in the darkness I roam.

> Jaguars hunt during the night 
>  https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZNGBZrdZyTE?ecver=2

Comment: Yea or Tiger: As Tiger Woods, as Tiger tank and Tiger animal.

Comment: But Tiger Woods, nor tiger tanks, are directly meant to take you home ;)

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> [Wand](https://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wand)

Made of wood and metal, I get you home.

> Made with wood and metal. Wands can [teleport or apparate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102813/does-a-wizard-need-a-wand-to-apparate) you home.

Made of blood and flesh, in the darkness I roam.

> Wands are made with dragon [Heartstring](https://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon)(flesh, blood). Dragons roam in the dark sky

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) while you're here (you'll also get a badge)? By the way, Stack Exchange is trying to make the site https compliant, so in your next edit, would you mind changing your link to Sci-fi SE to https? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you alternatively

> Buggy

Made of wood and metal, I get you home.

> Another name for a cart pulled by a horse.

Made of blood and flesh, in the darkness I roam.

> Bugs have blood and flesh and roam the night

Answer (score 1):

Are you alternatively

> A pirate?

Made of weed and metal, I get you home

> Pirates would make you walk the plank or just kill you and you would get you home (they also may ransom you)

Made of blood and flesh, in the darkness I roam.

> They roam around a lot as they are pirates